# With python's selenium package, Why Chromedriver starts to display video instead of downloading when click on a tag?

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, windows-10

- Operating System: Windows 10, 64 bit
- Editor: VSCode 1.55
- Python: 3.9.0

  - selenium: 3.141.0

I want Chromedriver to start downloading the video when I click on a tag.

But instead, it opens a new tab and starts to display the video.

The site that I'm trying to download from: https://www.aparat.com/v/9y8M5?playlist=683341

[image]

[image]

[image]

here is my code if needed:

[image]

I will appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose, you just want to download the video, and don't care about the way.

Actually, you have got the source url of the video, so you can download the video directely instead of clicking some element to show a Download Dialog.

A demo like this, replace `b.pop().click()` with it:

```
import requests

url = b.pop().get_attribute('href')
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('video.mp4', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: In url equation you meant b.pop().get_attribute('href')?

Comment: @Zighol In your code, `b` is the element `<a>`, so `b.get_attribute('href')` will get the url

Comment: b is a list of a tag elements because I used find_elements

Comment: Anyway, your proposed code with above edit that I said works for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Zighol Very sorry, I missed the `s` in `find_elements_xxx`. But I'm glad you got my way of solving the problem.

Comment: No problem. Thank you so much for your time.